# Не устанавливается bigartm python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

скачал релиз с github https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm/releases, запустил файл python/setup.py

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bigartm-0.10.1\python\setup.py", line 205, in <module>
    if sys.argv[1] == "bdist_wheel":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Ссылка на код этого файла: https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm/blob/master/python/setup.py

При вводе в командной строке `setup.py bdist_wheel`

Выводит ошибку:

```
C:\bigartm-0.10.1\python>setup.py bdist_wheel
running bdist_wheel
running build
Generating ./artm/wrapper/messages_pb2.py...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bigartm-0.10.1\python\setup.py", line 210, in <module>
    setup(**setup_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\bigartm-0.10.1\python\setup.py", line 109, in run
    generate_proto_files(
  File "C:\bigartm-0.10.1\python\setup.py", line 82, in generate_proto_files
    raise ValueError("No protobuf compiler executable was found!")
ValueError: No protobuf compiler executable was found!
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: есть подозрение что там нужно чтобы вы сделали `setup.py bdist_wheel`

Comment: @Twiss попробовал этот способ, опять вылазит ошибка.

Comment: тут проблема с компиляцией уже, [документация](https://bigartm.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation/windows.html)

Comment: @Twiss в документации написано,что в скаченном релизе есть папка bin, но ее нет нигде, документация мне не помогла

Comment: Есть подозрение что вам надо еще эту штуку поставить: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

Comment: Так как ошибка говорит о том, что функция поиска (# Find the Protocol Buffer Compiler.) ничего не возвращает